# how to read posted FormUrlEncodedContent in asp.net core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

in `asp.net core web api` i have a `POST` method that get username and password in `FormUrlEncodedContent` format from client. But the **"entry"** parameter is `null`.

how can i access the username and password in Login method in web api ?

here is my code:

client:

```
public async Task<string> login2(string command , string username , string password)
   {
        string exist = string.Empty;

        FormUrlEncodedContent dataForm = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("username",username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",password)
        });

        var resp = await http.PostAsync(command,dataForm);
        exist = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return exist;
   }
```

server :

```
public IActionResult Login([FromForm] string entry)
  {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             return BadRequest(ModelState);
         }

       Console.WriteLine(entry);

       return Ok(entry);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model to hold the posted information

```
public class LoginModel {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

and update the action to expect that from the from

```
public IActionResult Login([FromForm] LoginModel entry) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    // access the username and password
    var username = entry.username;
    var password = entry.password;

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: is this the only solution? i mean , is there a solution without creating model?